# Get difference of two dates and then return an alert when submit

Tags: javascript, laravel

So I'm trying to return an error message when a user selets dates that go more than 2 for a specific type currently I'm trying to get the dates with js and I tried using it like this on the blade view to check if it returns anything but it doesn't show any alert

Javascript

```
function parseDate(str) {
    var mdy = str.split('/');
    return new Date(mdy[2], mdy[0]-1, mdy[1]);
}

function datediff(first, second) {
    return Math.round((second-first)/(1000*60*60*24));
}

if(datediff > 2){
    alert("Its more than 2");
}
```

And this is how I select the dates

```
<div class="form-group">
                            <label>From Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="datepicker0" type="text" class="form-control @error('from') is-invalid @enderror" name="from" required="" id="first">

                                @error('from')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>To Date</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input class="datepicker1" type="text" class="form-control @error('to') is-invalid @enderror" name="to" required="" id="second">

                                @error('to')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Nothing returns for this might it be because I'm using datepicker?

Comment: The `datediff` function is never greater than 2, you've to call your function with parameters.

Comment: @Teemu But I pick the parameters when I select the date wouldn't that work?

Comment: Nope, `function datediff(first, second) {...}` expects two arguments, and would return `NaN`, if the parameters are not passed.

Comment: How can I connect them to get value from the selected date when submitted?